# Python - why is this wrong?

Tags: python

This don't works and I wish to know what I did wrong.

```
targets= ["a","b","c"]
tmplist= ["d","z","x"]
value = [ (x,y) for x in targets for y in tmplist]
```

I know this issue can be solved with zip function, but I want to do it without zip. Thanks for any help

EDIT: I'm very sorry for not being clear, I have been distracted.

Comment: It doesn't work because `targets` isn't defined. Neither is `tmplist`.

Comment: Well, presumably they are defined, but we need to see them to know why they aren't working. Also, when you say it doesn't work, what does that mean? Is it an error or is the list comprehension empty? And lastly, why not use zip? Using functional tools is a good approach to get used to.

Comment: What do you mean "don't works [sic]"? Errors (provide full traceback)? Unexpected outputs (provide inputs and expected and actual outputs)?

Comment: What error are you getting? The syntax is correct.

Comment: OK, this is better, but you still need to explain what you want to do, what outcome you expect from this operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Luckily my crystal ball is working today so I can guess what you mean when you say it isn't working. Of course, you might have made it easier by actually explaining, but there we go.

If you just want a list of (x, y) pairs then zip is the way to go. The syntax you have does something else: for *each* element in targets it iterates completely through all elements in tmplist. This is exactly equivalent to:

```
 for x in targets:
    for y in tmplist:
        value.append((x, y))
```

So for a pair of lists ['a', 'b', 'c'] and [1, 2, 3] you would get: 
[('a', 1), ('a', 2), ('a', 3), ('b', 1), ('b', 2), ('b', 3), ('c', 1), ('c', 2), ('c', 3)]